# Track React Native mobile app screen view with the AWS Amplify Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, analytics, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I'm using the AWS amplify analytics for my React native mobile app for iOS and Android to see user behavior.

It is clear [how to add a custom event to the AWS Pinpoint vis AWS amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics#recording-custom-events). However, I don't see any information about how to track pageviews(views on each screen) on the mobile app except for the web app.

**Does anyone know how to implement screen views on React Native mobile app using AWS Amplify Analytics?**

I like to see when a user gets on the app, what screens they go on and how much time they spend on those screens.